# How to allocate the label center of case using sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, mathjax

I'm writing equations using `sphinx`. My code looks like this:

```
.. math::
  :label: eq1

  \begin{eqnarray}
  \begin{cases}
  a_{11}x_{1} + \dots + a_{1m}x_{m} = b_1\\
  a_{21}x_{1} + \dots + a_{2m}x_{m} = b_2
  \end{cases}
  \end{eqnarray}
```

This displays the label (1) on the right side of the first line, but I would to allocate it the center of this `{cases}`, namely, between the first and the second line.

How do I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. The easier it is to copy and test your code, the more likely your question will be answered and can help others in a similar situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question seems to pertain principally about MathJax usage.

By some experimenting I discovered it understands `\smash` and that using it provides the hoped for label placement. But perhaps there is some MathJax setting which would avoid using this `\smash`. Besides `\smash` works fine only for two or three "cases".

I have moved the `\smash` approach to second part, where also its drawbacks are explained. Indeed, I have since found a half-satisfying CSS approach.

At any rate, don't use `eqnarray` there.

### CSS based approach

Create a file `_static/custom.css` in your source repertory with these contents.

```
.MathJax_Display {
    transform: translate(0%,-50%) translate(0%,8px);
}

div.math {
    transform: translate(0%,50%);
}
```

Add this at end of conf.py:

```
if html_theme != 'alabaster':
    def setup(app):
        app.add_stylesheet('custom.css')
```

For example I obtain this with  `'classic'` theme:

[image]

This works also with `'agogo'` and `'alabaster'` themes, but some fine tuning might be needed for equations with only one line to be positioned like the label.

In the case RTD theme it does not work at all.

Support may be browser dependent.

---

### `\smash` approach

```
Text before.

.. math::
   :label: eq1

   \smash{\begin{cases}
   a_{11}x_{1} + \dots + a_{1m}x_{m} &= b_1\\
   a_{21}x_{1} + \dots + a_{2m}x_{m} &= b_2
   \end{cases}}

Text after.
```

I get from `make html` (with classic theme)

[image]

`conf.py` contains

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.mathjax',
]

html_theme = 'classic'
```

By the way your `eqnarray` is not good mark-up. IF you use it you should use `:nowrap:` option. See [Sphinx doc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/math.html?highlight=numfig#directive-math).

**Note** Of course usage of `cases` here is dubious because your example is one of equations. I added `&`'s but the spacing is one appropriate for `cases`, which is surely not the one expected. So remove them.

Here is mark-up which does not abuse `cases` environment:

```
Text before.

.. math::
   :label: eq1

   \smash{\left\{\begin{aligned}
   a_{11}x_{1} + \dots + a_{1m}x_{m} &= b_1\\
   a_{21}x_{1} + \dots + a_{2m}x_{m} &= b_2
   \end{aligned}\right.}

Text after.
```

**CAVEAT** The smash trick only works with two (perhaps three) equations, even in MathJax.

[image]

Comment: Jut FYI, sphinx is handling the labels directly, not through MathJax.  MathJax would have centered the tag if it had been asked to handle the equation label.  Apparently sphinx's equation numbering doesn't handle multiline equations very well.

Comment: @DavideCervone yes, Sphinx uses class "eqno" for the label. (this [issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2785) at least popped up in search and there is also a [RTD issue](https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/301)). Regarding multiline maths (which isn't the case here because all is wrapped into one `split` environment), there has been start of discussion about a `labels` option [here](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/4166#pullrequestreview-84060954), [also here](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/4166#issuecomment-352506018).

Comment: @DavidCervone If we ask user to insert `\label` LaTeX mark-up inside the math which will be rendered by Sphinx, there is no way for Sphinx mechanism of cross references (which uses reST syntax, with additional roles added by Sphinx) to work out. Is `\label` the way to get MathJax do the numbering itself?

Comment: This is pretty far off topic for this group.  Perhaps we should take this to the [MathJax Users Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mathjax-users)?